# ASP.NET Question: Request.Url.Host property

Tags: asp.net

Does this property return, e.g., www1.domain.com, www2.domain.com, etc.

And if there is any exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - it can return an IP address. Or an internal host name. Basically it returns what the client sent in the host header, and that can even be bogus, depending on how IIS is configured.